# Average time between repairs by unit

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

We have about 275,000 units.  These units have repair records detailing different repairs.  I'm trying to figure out what the average time between repairs is on any given unit.

We have a workorders table, which contains the unit_no, and a lineitems table which contains the repair codes.  For example:

workorders table:

```
wo_master_number | unit_no | wo_date
100              | 50      | 2016-02-15
101              | 51      | 2016-06-10
102              | 52      | 2016-12-21
103              | 53      | 2017-06-12
```

lineitems table:

```
    wo_master_number | repair_code
    100              | 3311
    100              | 4358
    101              | 3311
    102              | 3311
    103              | 3311
```

In this example, we see repair_code 3311 has been done 4 times.  The days elapsed between the repairs... 116 days, 194 days, and 173 days.  That means (116+194+173)/3 = 161 days on average between repair of ID 3311

```
CREATE TABLE `wo_workorders` (
  `unique_key` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `wo_master_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `revision_status` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wo_status` char(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workorder_no` char(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_no` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  [omitted for brevity]

  PRIMARY KEY (`unique_key`),
  KEY `workorder_no` (`workorder_no`),
  KEY `unit_no` (`unit_no`),
  KEY `wo_date` (`workorder_date`),
  [omitted for brevity]

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1860068 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `wo_lineitems` (
  `unique_key` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `wo_unique_key` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wo_master_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line_item_unique_key` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rep_code` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  [omitted for brevity]

  PRIMARY KEY (`unique_key`),
  KEY `wo_unique_key` (`wo_unique_key`),
  KEY `wo-master_revision` (`wo_master_number`,`revision_number`),
  KEY `rep_code` (`rep_code`),
  [omitted for brevity]

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8935142 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I would like the output grouped by repair code with the average time between repairs of said type.

Here's what I'm trying right now:

```
SELECT n.rep_code,AVG(diff) avg
FROM ( 
    SELECT a.rep_code,DATEDIFF(MIN(b.workorder_date), a.workorder_date) diff
    FROM 
         ( SELECT o.workorder_date
                , x.rep_code ,
                o.wo_master_number,
                o.unit_no
             FROM wo_workorders o
             JOIN wo_lineitems x ON x.wo_master_number = o.wo_master_number
             -- where o.workorder_date > 20170601
         ) a
      JOIN 
         ( SELECT o.workorder_date
                , x.rep_code ,
                o.wo_master_number,
                o.unit_no
             FROM wo_workorders o
             JOIN wo_lineitems x ON x.wo_master_number = o.wo_master_number
             -- where o.workorder_date > 20170601
         ) b ON b.rep_code = a.rep_code
       AND b.workorder_date > a.workorder_date
       -- where a.workorder_date > 20170601 -- added for speed
     GROUP
        BY a.wo_master_number
         , a.unit_no
         , a.workorder_date
         , a.rep_code
) n
GROUP BY rep_code;
```

(sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28682e/1)

Except its too slow to run:
[image: explain plan]

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, will do now

Comment: Please provide the EXPLAIN. (An upvote would also be nice)

Comment: i guess the only thing really worth indexing here is `(rep_code,workorder_date)`

Comment: Some things are better (or at least more easily) done in app code, not SQL.

Comment: @RickJames that is eventually what I ended up doing.  I wrote about a 300 line java program... pretty messy code, but it got the job done for one time use.

Answer (score 1):

E.g:

```
 SELECT n.repair_code
     , AVG(diff) avg
  FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT a.repair_code
     , DATEDIFF(MIN(b.workorder_date), a.workorder_date) diff
  FROM 
     ( SELECT o.*
            , x.repair_code 
         FROM workorders o
         JOIN lineitems x
           ON x.wo_master_number = o.wo_master_number
     ) a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT o.*
            , x.repair_code 
         FROM workorders o
         JOIN lineitems x
           ON x.wo_master_number = o.wo_master_number
     ) b
    ON b.repair_code = a.repair_code
   AND b.workorder_date > a.workorder_date
 GROUP
    BY a.wo_master_number
     , a.unit_no
     , a.workorder_date
     , a.repair_code
) n
GROUP BY repair_code;
```

Comment: I think, theoretically at least, this is what I was trying to get to.  The only problem is, its too slow to run (I ran it on just a few thousand workorders, took about 7200 seconds - I have a total of 1.6m workorders.)

Comment: @Ted So let's start with the basics. Define PRIMARY KEYs on all your tables, and then update your question to provide SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables, together with the result of the EXPLAIN for the above.

Comment: Updated.  There are some indexes (which I didnt know about) also one thing we can limit on is `where wo_status = 'C'`

Answer (score 0):

You can just calculate the average:

```
select li.repair_code, avg(datediff(min(wo_date), max(wo_date)))
from workorders wo join
     lineitems li
     on li.wo_master_number = wo.wo_master_number
group by li.repair_code;
```

Comment: `Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function`